# Problems with linking CUDA for running fastHOG algorithm

Tags: c, linux, linker, makefile

I am trying to set up the fastHOG codebase in my linux server, but unable to finish it as i am getting heap of link errors. I am giving here a sample portion of the link errors

```
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x910): undefined reference    to  'cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x944): undefined reference   to  'cudaGetErrorString'
/home/n8385106/bin/contrib/qut/qutanomaly/matlab/person- detector/fasthog/obj/release/HOG/HOGHistogram.cu.o: In function 'InitHistograms(int, int, int, int, int, float)':
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xac0): undefined reference   to 'cudaCreateChannelDesc'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xafe): undefined reference to  'cudaMallocArray'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xb46): undefined reference to 'cudaMemcpyToArray'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc3d): undefined reference to 'cudaMemcpyToSymbol'
 tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc63): undefined reference to 'cudaMemcpyToSymbol'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc89): undefined reference to 'cudaMemcpyToSymbol'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xcae): undefined reference to 'cudaMemcpyToSymbol'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xccd): undefined reference to 'cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xd01): undefined reference to 'cudaGetErrorString'
 tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xd15): undefined reference to 'cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xd29): undefined reference to 'cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00006d91_00000000-1_HOGHistogram.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xd3d): undefined reference to 'cudaGetErrorString'
```

It seems the linker didn't realize any of the linker libraries provided in the make file. It did not say anything like "was unable to find this library" but it avoided all the information provided about the libraries to be linked such as

```
# Libs
LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/cuda/lib64 -L$(LIBDIR) - L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) 

# If dynamically linking to CUDA and CUDART, we exclude the libraries from the LIB
 ifeq ($(USECUDADYNLIB),1)
 LIB += ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) $(CUDPPLIB) ${LIB} 
 else
  # static linking, we will statically link against CUDA and CUDART
 ifeq ($(USEDRVAPI),1)
 LIB += -lcuda   ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) $(CUDPPLIB) ${LIB} 
  else
 LIB += -lcudart ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) $(CUDPPLIB) ${LIB}
 endif
 endif

 ifeq ($(USECUFFT),1)
 ifeq ($(emu),1)
 LIB += -lcufftemu
 else
  LIB += -lcufft
 endif
endif

ifeq ($(USECUBLAS),1)
 ifeq ($(emu),1)
LIB += -lcublasemu
 else
  LIB += -lcublas
 endif
 endif
```

I was able to create all the object files but problem is comming during the linking process, I am a newbie to CUDA, Can anyone please help me to sort this out?

My OS is 64 bit linux

Edited : My MakeFile

```
# Add source files here
EXECUTABLE  := fastHOG
# C/C++ source files (compiled with gcc / c++)
 CCFILES        := \
    fastHOG.cpp \
# HOG UTILS 
 CCUTILS        := \
    ImageWindow.cpp \
# CC HOG 
 CCHOG      := \
    HOGImage.cpp \
    HOGEngine.cpp \
    HOGNMS.cpp \
# CUDA HOG 
 CUFILES        := \
    HOGEngineDevice.cu \
    HOGConvolution.cu \
    HOGHistogram.cu \
    HOGPadding.cu \
    HOGScale.cu \
    HOGSVMSlider.cu \
    HOGUtils.cu \
################################################################################
# Rules and targets

include common.mk
```

Contents of the common.mk file

```
  ################################################################################
#
# Copyright 1993-2006 NVIDIA Corporation.  All rights reserved.
#
################################################################################
#
# Common build script
#
################################################################################
 .SUFFIXES : .cu .cu_dbg.o .c_dbg.o .cpp_dbg.o .cu_rel.o .c_rel.o .cpp_rel.o .cubin

 #Add new SM Versions here as devices with new Compute Capability are released
 SM_VERSIONS := sm_10 sm_11 sm_12 sm_13

 CUDA_INSTALL_PATH ?= fasthoglib/cuda/cuda

 ifdef cuda-install
  CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := $(cuda-install)
 endif

  # detect OS
  OSUPPER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
  OSLOWER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
  # 'linux' is output for Linux system, 'darwin' for OS X
  DARWIN = $(strip $(findstring DARWIN, $(OSUPPER)))


# Basic directory setup for SDK
# (override directories only if they are not already defined)
SRCDIR      ?= 
SRCDIRUTILS ?= Utils
SRCDIRHOG   ?= HOG
ROOTDIR     ?= /home/n8385106/src/saivt-vxl/contrib/qut/qutanomaly/matlab/pedestrian-detector/fasthoglib/cuda/sdk
ROOTBINDIR  ?= /home/n8385106/bin/contrib/qut/qutanomaly/matlab/person-detector/fasthog/bin
BINDIR      ?= $(ROOTBINDIR)
ROOTOBJDIR  ?= /home/n8385106/bin/contrib/qut/qutanomaly/matlab/person-detector/fasthog/obj
LIBDIR      := $(ROOTDIR)/C/lib
COMMONDIR   := $(ROOTDIR)/C/common

# Compilers
NVCC       := $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc 
CXX        := g++
CC         := gcc
LINK       := g++ -fPIC

# Includes
INCLUDES  += -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/cuda/include -I$(COMMONDIR)/inc 
# architecture flag for cubin build
CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG := -m32

# Warning flags
CXXWARN_FLAGS := \
    -W -Wall \
    -Wimplicit \
    -Wswitch \
    -Wformat \
    -Wchar-subscripts \
    -Wparentheses \
    -Wmultichar \
    -Wtrigraphs \
    -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wcast-align \
    -Wreturn-type \
    -Wno-unused-function \
    $(SPACE)

CWARN_FLAGS := $(CXXWARN_FLAGS) \
    -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -Wmissing-declarations \
    -Wnested-externs \
    -Wmain \

# Compiler-specific flags
NVCCFLAGS :=   
CXXFLAGS  := $(CXXWARN_FLAGS)
CFLAGS    := $(CWARN_FLAGS)

# Common flags
COMMONFLAGS += $(INCLUDES) -DUNIX

# Debug/release configuration
ifeq ($(dbg),1)
    COMMONFLAGS += -g
    NVCCFLAGS   += -D_DEBUG
    BINSUBDIR   := debug
    LIBSUFFIX   := D
else 
    COMMONFLAGS += -O3 
    BINSUBDIR   := release
    LIBSUFFIX   :=
    NVCCFLAGS   += --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing
    CXXFLAGS    += -fno-strict-aliasing
    CFLAGS      += -fno-strict-aliasing
endif

# append optional arch/SM version flags (such as -arch sm_11)
#NVCCFLAGS += $(SMVERSIONFLAGS)

# architecture flag for cubin build
CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG := -m32

# detect if 32 bit or 64 bit system
HP_64 = $(shell uname -m | grep 64)

# OpenGL is used or not (if it is used, then it is necessary to include GLEW)
ifeq ($(USEGLLIB),1)

    ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
        OPENGLLIB := -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries -lGL -lGLU $(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER)/libGLEW.a
    else
        OPENGLLIB := -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu

        ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
            OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW -L/usr/X11R6/lib
        else
            OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW_x86_64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib64
        endif
    endif

    CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG := -m64
endif

ifeq ($(USEGLUT),1)
    ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
        OPENGLLIB += -framework GLUT
    else
        OPENGLLIB += -lglut
    endif
endif

ifeq ($(USEPARAMGL),1)
    PARAMGLLIB := -lparamgl$(LIBSUFFIX)
endif

ifeq ($(USERENDERCHECKGL),1)
    RENDERCHECKGLLIB := -lrendercheckgl$(LIBSUFFIX)
endif
USECUDPP := 1;
ifeq ($(USECUDPP), 1)
    ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
        CUDPPLIB := -lcudpp
    else
        CUDPPLIB := -lcudpp64
    endif

    CUDPPLIB := $(CUDPPLIB)$(LIBSUFFIX)

    ifeq ($(emu), 1)
        CUDPPLIB := $(CUDPPLIB)_emu
    endif
endif

# Libs
LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/cuda/lib64 -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) 

# If dynamically linking to CUDA and CUDART, we exclude the libraries from the LIB
ifeq ($(USECUDADYNLIB),1)
     LIB += ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) $(CUDPPLIB) ${LIB} 
else
# static linking, we will statically link against CUDA and CUDART
  ifeq ($(USEDRVAPI),1)
     LIB += -lcuda   ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) $(CUDPPLIB) ${LIB} 
  else
     LIB += -lcudart ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) $(CUDPPLIB) ${LIB}
  endif
endif

ifeq ($(USECUFFT),1)
  ifeq ($(emu),1)
    LIB += -lcufftemu
  else
    LIB += -lcufft
  endif
endif

ifeq ($(USECUBLAS),1)
  ifeq ($(emu),1)
    LIB += -lcublasemu
  else
    LIB += -lcublas
  endif
endif

# Lib/exe configuration
ifneq ($(STATIC_LIB),)
    TARGETDIR := $(LIBDIR)
    TARGET   := $(subst .a,$(LIBSUFFIX).a,$(LIBDIR)/$(STATIC_LIB))
    LINKLINE  = ar rucv $(TARGET) $(OBJS) 
else
    LIB += -lcutil$(LIBSUFFIX)
    # Device emulation configuration
    ifeq ($(emu), 1)
        NVCCFLAGS   += -deviceemu
        CUDACCFLAGS += 
        BINSUBDIR   := emu$(BINSUBDIR)
        # consistency, makes developing easier
        CXXFLAGS        += -D__DEVICE_EMULATION__
        CFLAGS          += -D__DEVICE_EMULATION__
    endif
    TARGETDIR := $(BINDIR)/$(BINSUBDIR)
    TARGET    := $(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)
    #fltk

    LIB += -lfltk2 -lXft -lfltk2_images -lXext -lXinerama -lXi
    #boost thread for interface
    LIB += -lboost_thread
    #read images in HOGImage from file
    LIB := /pkg/suse11/cuda/4.2/sdk/CUDALibraries/common/FreeImage/lib/linux/libfreeimage64.a
    LINKLINE  = $(LINK) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
endif

# check if verbose 
ifeq ($(verbose), 1)
    VERBOSE := 
else
    VERBOSE := @
endif

################################################################################
# Check for input flags and set compiler flags appropriately
################################################################################
ifeq ($(fastmath), 1)
    NVCCFLAGS += -use_fast_math
endif

ifeq ($(keep), 1)
    NVCCFLAGS += -keep
    NVCC_KEEP_CLEAN := *.i* *.cubin *.cu.c *.cudafe* *.fatbin.c *.ptx
endif

ifdef maxregisters
    NVCCFLAGS += -maxrregcount $(maxregisters)
endif

# Add cudacc flags
NVCCFLAGS += $(CUDACCFLAGS)

# workaround for mac os x cuda 1.1 compiler issues
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
    NVCCFLAGS += --host-compilation C
endif

# Add common flags
NVCCFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS  += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CFLAGS    += $(COMMONFLAGS)

ifeq ($(nvcc_warn_verbose),1)
    NVCCFLAGS += $(addprefix --compiler-options ,$(CXXWARN_FLAGS)) 
    NVCCFLAGS += --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing
endif

################################################################################
# Set up object files
################################################################################
OBJDIR := $(ROOTOBJDIR)/$(BINSUBDIR)
OBJS  +=  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.cpp.o,$(notdir $(CCFILES)))

OBJDIRUTILS := $(ROOTOBJDIR)/$(BINSUBDIR)/$(SRCDIRUTILS)
OBJS +=  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIRUTILS)/%.cpp.o,$(notdir $(CCUTILS)))

OBJDIRHOG := $(ROOTOBJDIR)/$(BINSUBDIR)/$(SRCDIRHOG)
OBJS +=  $(patsubst %.cu,$(OBJDIRHOG)/%.cu.o,$(notdir $(CUFILES)))
OBJS +=  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIRHOG)/%.cpp.o,$(notdir $(CCHOG)))

################################################################################
# Set up cubin files
################################################################################
CUBINDIR := $(SRCDIR)data
CUBINS +=  $(patsubst %.cu,$(CUBINDIR)/%.cubin,$(notdir $(CUBINFILES)))

################################################################################
# Rules
################################################################################
$(OBJDIR)/%.c.o : $(SRCDIR)%.c $(C_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIRUTILS)/%.cpp.o : $(SRCDIRUTILS)%.cpp $(C_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.cpp.o : $(SRCDIR)%.cpp $(C_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIRHOG)/%.cpp.o : $(SRCDIRHOG)%.cpp $(C_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.cu.o : $(SRCDIR)%.cu $(CU_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIRHOG)/%.cu.o : $(SRCDIRHOG)%.cu $(CU_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(CUBINDIR)/%.cubin : $(SRCDIR)%.cu cubindirectory
    $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) $(CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $@ -cubin $<

#
# The following definition is a template that gets instantiated for each SM
# version (sm_10, sm_13, etc.) stored in SMVERSIONS.  It does 2 things:
# 1. It adds to OBJS a .cu_sm_XX.o for each .cu file it finds in CUFILES_sm_XX.
# 2. It generates a rule for building .cu_sm_XX.o files from the corresponding 
#    .cu file.
#
# The intended use for this is to allow Makefiles that use common.mk to compile
# files to different Compute Capability targets (aka SM arch version).  To do
# so, in the Makefile, list files for each SM arch separately, like so:
#
# CUFILES_sm_10 := mycudakernel_sm10.cu app.cu
# CUFILES_sm_12 := anothercudakernel_sm12.cu
#
define SMVERSION_template
OBJS += $(patsubst %.cu,$(OBJDIR)/%.cu_$(1).o,$(notdir $(CUFILES_$(1))))
$(OBJDIR)/%.cu_$(1).o : $(SRCDIR)%.cu $(CU_DEPS)
    $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) -o $$@ -c $$< $(NVCCFLAGS) -arch $(1)
endef

# This line invokes the above template for each arch version stored in
# SM_VERSIONS.  The call function invokes the template, and the eval
# function interprets it as make commands.
$(foreach smver,$(SM_VERSIONS),$(eval $(call SMVERSION_template,$(smver))))

$(TARGET): makedirectories $(OBJS) $(CUBINS) Makefile
    $(VERBOSE)$(LINKLINE)

cubindirectory:
    $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(CUBINDIR)

makedirectories:
    $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(LIBDIR)
    $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(OBJDIRUTILS)   
    $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(OBJDIRHOG)     
    $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)

tidy :-lboost_thread 
    $(VERBOSE)find . | egrep "#" | xargs rm -f
    $(VERBOSE)find . | egrep "\~" | xargs rm -f

clean : tidy
    $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(OBJS)
    $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(CUBINS)
    $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(TARGET)
    $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(NVCC_KEEP_CLEAN)

clobber : clean
    $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(ROOTOBJDIR)
```

Comment: Clearly the CUDA runtime library (libcudart) is not being linked. Why it happens is impossible to say, because you haven't showed the linking command. A snippet of Makefile isn't enough to diagnose the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I have added all the snippets, can you have a look again please?

Comment: You broke the common.mk file when you modified it. I have voted to close this - [SO] isn't a typo spotting service and this question will *never* be useful to anyone but you.

Comment: FYI - Here is the original code http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~lav/Papers/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09.html, i just added another path to the existing configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common.mk has been broken (presumably by a modification you made to it) here:

```
LIB := /pkg/suse11/cuda/4.2/sdk/CUDALibraries/common/FreeImage/lib/linux/libfreeimage64.a
```

This is undoubtedly not what you want, it is destroying all of the carefully crafted library dependencies assigned above it. I guess you intended something like

```
LIB += /pkg/suse11/cuda/4.2/sdk/CUDALibraries/common/FreeImage/lib/linux/libfreeimage64.a
```